# TFS rollback to a changeset

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

there are lot of content giving solution around this question, but answers were not convincing so I had to post here.

We had two branches of our code, I merged one into another, but other team members had seen lot of overrides in the merged version, so all that I want is to rollback the project to a version (x) before the merge(x+1) happenend.

I have VS 2012/ Eclipse TFS everywhere 2011.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012, you have a few options.

**Rollback to a specific version**

In Source Control Explorer:

1. Right Click the branch you wish to roll back
2. Click `Rollback...`
3. Choose `Rollback to a specific version`
4. Enter the changeset number you wish to roll back to.

**Rollback a single changeset** (you can do this through the dialog loaded above too)

1. Right click the changeset you wish to rollback
2. Choose `Rollback entire changset`

Checkin the rollback.

Comment: I couldn't find the 'Rollback' option in the Context menu when right-clicking an item. I want to rollback the entire solution to a specific changeset.

Comment: The rollback button is available only if you have TFS Power Tools installed. Otherwise go with Rollback a specific changeset in the history of your branch.